# Apply custom function (creating HTML tables) to every column of a data frame using purrr / map

Tags: html, r, dplyr, iteration, purrr

I have a custom function, which generates HTML tables with `DT:datatable` and works well when applied without iterative approaches.

```
function_datatable <- function(df, input_var) {

  df %>% 
    group_by(!!enquo(input_var)) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
    filter(! is.na(!!enquo(input_var))) %>%
    DT::datatable()
  
}
```

However, it does not work when applied to an iterative approach for example with `purrr::map` or `map2`. My goal is to apply this function to every variable of a data frame / tibble. The goal is to apply this in an R Markdown, where a variety of variables should be displayed one after the other. So the syntax should be something like this (code obviously does not work)

```
df %>% map(function_datatable)
```

I got a couple of different error message when trying out different approaches and combinations. Some were related to `group_by` and `character` others to the datatable/htmlwidget class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code ("state of the art" tidyverse syntax). Some tidyeval stuff was needed in order to deal with the correct way of programming the function. Thanks @Manuel Zambelli for the `map()` answer!

```
library(tidyverse)

function_datatable <- function(input_var, df) {
  
  df %>% 
    group_by(across(all_of(input_var))) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
    filter(! is.na(!!rlang::sym(input_var))) %>% 
    DT::datatable()
  
}

map(names(mtcars), function_datatable, mtcars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with mtcars and removing last line of your function.

```
require(tidyverse)

dataf <- tibble(mtcars)

function_datatable <- function(col_name, df) {
  
  return(df %>% 
    group_by_at(col_name) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
    filter(! is.na(!!enquo(col_name))))
  
}

map(names(dataf), function_datatable, dataf)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the contribution. Unfortunately your approach does not work accordingly. The iterative approach works, however, the function just returns the total n (which is obviously the same for each variable/column

Comment: I edited the answer, now it groups correctly by each row and produces the desidered (i guess) output. Let me know if it fits your needs

Comment: It now works kind of, but I replaced `group_by_at` with `group_by(across(all_of()))`. However `filter` does not work since the NAs are still returned

Comment: group_by(across(all_of())) doesn't work to me

Comment: You might have to put the column in quotes when you try to apply the function manually. The `map()` works anyway

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.